# Pasar un parámetro a la shell de linux para clonar desde un repositorio git

Tags: linux, git, parametros, sh, git-clone

Tengo un script.sh que realiza la operación "*clone*" de un repositorio git.

Actualmente, el script funciona correctamente con el *branch* objetivo escrito en duro en la línea correspondiente.

```
/usr/bin/git clone https://my-url-repository  --branch master --single-branch
```

Si a "*master*" lo reemplazo por "$1",

```
/usr/bin/git clone https://my-url-repository  --branch $1 --single-branch
```

No se puede completar la operación ya que no toma correctamente el *branch* y lanza un fatal error.

> ```
> warning: Could not find remote branch e to clone.
> fatal: Remote branch e not found in upstream origin
> ```

Sin embargo, si imprimo por pantalla el parámetro $1 o ${1}, se visualiza correctamente el valor ingresado.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    echo Building from branch "["$1"]"
else
    echo "Please, enter branch name"
    exit
fi
```

¿Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Y cómo estás invocando tu shell?

Comment: Desde la carpeta contenedora, con pemisos de root hago "./script.sh master"

Comment: Lo probé con un archivo `script.sh` con esta línea `/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/porloscerros/porloscerros.github.io.git  --branch $1 --single-branch` y ejecutando en una terminal `./script.sh master`, y funciona... > `Clonando en 'porloscerros.github.io'...`. Lo que veo raro en el warn es que dice que no encuentra la rama llamada `e` > `Remote branch e not found ...`

Comment: hay algún error que no aparece en la pregunta, estoy con @porloscerrosΨ en que no encaja. ¿Puedes revisar todo el código y actualizar la pregunta?

Comment: Tal cual, también me llamó la atención esa "e" en ambos mensajes, ingrese lo que ingrese, exista el branch o no, siempre tira esos mensajes de error. ¿Así que a vos sí te funciona? que raro che. Dale, reviso y si encuentro algún detalle nuevo actualizo. Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: en cualquier caso, siempre es bueno poner comillas para evitar problemas con espacios y demás: `/usr/bin/git clone https://my-url-repository  --branch "$1" --single-branch`

Comment: @DiegoRossi Sí, pero puse sólo esa línea y nada más. Si ejecuto el srcript con `./script.sh e` git me dá el mismo error que a vos, porque no hay una rama `e` en el repo, pero sí funciona con master.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios. Encontré otra manera de resolverlo. La pondré en la siguiente respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

No pude resolver específicamente el problema, pero sí encontré una alternativa igual de válida. En vez de esperar el parámetro en la llamada del script, dentro del mismo script solicito el ingreso del nombre del branch, y luego el *clone* se realiza sin problemas.

El código quedó así:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please, enter branch name"
read branchName
```

Y luego utilizo la variable así:

```
/usr/bin/git clone https://my-url-repository  --branch $branchName --single-branch
```